# Can I use a root Canonical User ID as a Principal for non-cloudfront access?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been asked to setup access to a specific bucket with access to another tenancy but using the root Canonical User ID and not using the Account ID. I have done a lot of research into this, and from my interpretations of the AWS documentation; the use of the Canonical User ID is used with ACLs, or CloudFront. I want to know if you just plug it into a standard bucket policy and have it work in place of a role.

This is how I would usually do this using an IAM role

```
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/policyonothertenancy"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"                
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is how I think you can do this with root user Canonical User IDs

```
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "CanonicalUser":"****************************************************************"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"                
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Would this work? Would this give access to the bucket from the other tenancy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. However, beware they are not equivalent. Granting access to a `CanonicalUser` is the same as granting access to all the users and roles in the account.